# Return Value From Subquery

Tags: sql, subquery, substring, case

How do I accomplish this without having to join two tables together?

```
CASE WHEN a.string IN(SELECT b.substring FROM b) THEN b.substring END AS [substring]
```

1. `b.substring` is holding multiple values.
2. `a.string` may contain one of the values of `b.substring`.
3. `a.string` is a comment box so I can't `JOIN` it with `b.substring`.

My goal is to return `b.substring` when there's a match. Here's an example:

- Assume table `a` contains two rows in column `string`: `stack` and `overflow`
- Assume table `b` contains two rows in column `substring`: `s` and `o`

The substring `o` is in `overflow`, so the return value would be `o` for this row.
The substring `s` is in `stack`, so the return value would be `s` for this row.

What's the best way to accomplish this?

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide more data and example about your question to give more useful answers.

Comment: Please tag your dbms and version, and format the code so it's not all on one line. Also, why do you not want to join the tables?

Comment: @Eli: Sample data of what b.substring and a.string can contain and what should/not be returned?

Comment: Will there ever be multiple `b.substring` values that contain the same `a.string` value?

Comment: if `b.substring` is a string like `'value1, value2, value3'` you cant do that. You need to split the string first same go for `a.string`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza. How would you split and compare the two strings to return a value?

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @HoneyBadger. I'm unable to because I'm essentially tried to find a match (substring) inside a string. I'm unable to link them because the values won't match.

Comment: We need a more detailed example so we can help you further. Anyway store multple value in the same field is a bad practice. My first suggestion is normalize your table so you dont have this kind of problems.

Comment: @digital.aaron. No, they won't match... `a.string` is a comment box where any user can type anything they want.

Comment: "b.substring is holding multiple values."  What is that supposed to mean?  A string column should contain one value, a string value (albeit composed of multiple characters).  I think you misunderstand something fundamental about SQL and data modeling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your example, here's how you can do what you're trying to do.

First, let's create some test data:

```
CREATE TABLE #table_a (id INT IDENTITY(1,1), string VARCHAR(15))
CREATE TABLE #table_b (id INT IDENTITY(1,1), substr VARCHAR(15))

INSERT INTO #table_a
(string)
VALUES ('stack'),('overflow')

INSERT INTO #table_b
(substr)
VALUES ('s'),('o')
```

Now you can query your data, only joining when `b.substr` is in `a.string`.

```
SELECT a.*
        ,b.substr
FROM #table_a a
LEFT JOIN #table_b b ON CHARINDEX(b.substr,a.string) > 0
```

This will give you all rows from `#table_a` and the `b.substr` values that are inside of `a.string`. If there's no match, `b.substr` will come back as `NULL`. Change the join to an `INNER JOIN` if you only want the records where there's a match.

Results:

```
id  string      substr
1   stack       s
2   overflow    o
```